# Typescript Project with JS Scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, scripting

I am building an app for internal usage in my company.
They use JS and I am building the app using Angular, so we decided to use typescript also for backend.
The problem is, there is a lot of scripts that we use like modules (to run mongodb functions for example), that are in javascript old language. How could I be able to work with them without having to refactor every single one of them?

Comment: _"javascript old language"_ hurts my heart. --- JavaScript works with typescript out of the box. What do you expect to go wrong?

Comment: hahaha By old language I meant old code patterns and everything.

Comment: Do you have an example of a script you can't use?

Comment: Some of them require javascript libs that don't have support to types. I didn't test them with typescript, I just want to know if I could have some trouble doing it.

Comment: Keep your js files and use the compiler option `"allowJs": true`. Or (because js is valid ts), just rename all your js files to .ts. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/migrating-from-javascript.html

Comment: Typescript is built with this use case in mind, so you'll have no problem interoping with js.